# Magento2 override core interface without extension Attribute in it

Tags: magento2, interface

I need to override this interface

**`Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface`**

I need to add setIncludeInMenu & getIncludeInMenu but there are no extension attributes, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Hey @Arjun have you fixed that out I'm also stock at the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Seems the only core class that implements `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryTreeInterface` is `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category`? This model has extension attributes as it also implements `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\CategoryInterface`. Can you maybe add extension attributes here?

If you've defined a custom class to override the implementation of `CategoryTreeInterface` (this can be done via `di.xml` class preference), you might just have to define getter/setter methods on the implementation class. Interfaces by definition cannot be amended with new methods.

Comment: Hi. can you please add some code how to achieve this?

Comment: Considering that the only core implementation of `CategoryTreeInterface` is `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category` - which has accessible extension attributes, I'd advise you follow the core devdocs: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

Comment: How can I do it without that